# Ghost blog - empty navigation

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I would like to setup a custom navigation on my ghost blog, yet even the simple walkthrough in the [documentation](http://themes.ghost.org/docs/navigation) is giving me blank output. I can also confirm that *{{#if @blog.navigation}}* evaluates true, as seen below.

ghost version: 0.11.4
database: mysql

> ghost/content/themes/omikron_1.4/partials/navigation.hbs

```
{{!-- Navigation --}}
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right doYouReadMe {{#if @blog.navigation}}weHaveNav{{/if}}">
    {{#foreach navigation}}
        <a href="{{url absolute="true"}}">{{label}}</a>
    {{/foreach}}
</ul>
```

I added the "doYouReadMe" class to confirm this file is actually being referenced. I also added the conditional to confirm that Ghost is seeing that navigation items exist. I then restarted ghost, and the navigation element is empty, with my added classes:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right doYouReadMe weHaveNav">
    ::before
    ::after
</ul>
```

Have also confirmed the values are in the db and they seem to be formatted properly. Additional evidence that there is no issue here is that the Navigation page in the admin area loads the content without any issues:

```
mysql> select settings.key, settings.value from settings where settings.key = 'navigation';
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| key        | value                                                                                                       |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| navigation | [{"label":"test google","url":"https://google.com"},{"label":"test facebook","url":"https://facebook.com"}] |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my theme's insertion of the navigation in my header partial.

Incorrect code was:

```
{{> navigation}}
```

I fixed this by correcting it to:

```
{{navigation}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ghost navigation is not understood as an array.
I had a simlar issue with the ghost-sidebar theme, which I solved using just:
`{{navigation}}`

and then styling the rendered elements. Replace your

```
{{#foreach navigation}}
    <a href="{{url absolute="true"}}">{{label}}</a>
{{/foreach}}
```

with the `{{navigation}}`

It is an issue related to the theme itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to handlebars, if you are using a custom template you can use this :

```
 {{#each @site.navigation}}
        <li class="nav-item {{#if this.current}} active {{/if}}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{this.url}}">{{{label}}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
```